# Method invocation failed because [System.ComObject] does not contain a method named 'IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName'

Tags: powershell, invalidoperationexception, method-invocation, methodnotfound

I've run into a problem that I can't figure out even after some frantic Googling. My PowerShell Script opens up a website, enters log in credentials and then selects a clickable link on the site. It is the clickable link I am having trouble with.

The following line works on my PC (Windows 10) but fails on my server (Server 2012):

```
$Link=$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.innerText -eq "Go to app"}
```

The error is:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.ComObject] does not contain a method named 
'IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName'.
At C:\script.ps1:53 char:1
$Link=$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.i ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName:String) [], RunTimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : MethodNotFound
```

This then makes my 'click' command fail:

```
$link.click()
```

Fails with:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\script.ps1:54 char:1
+link.click()
+~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RunTimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I've ensured that .NET 4.5 is installed on the server. Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated! Even if it is to change the way I select the clickable link altogether :)

Comment: Check `Get-Member` on your object.  It might be named something different like HTML2 since it's a different OS version.

Comment: Thanks I ran the following on both servers:
[System.__ComObject] | gm
The closest I can see is 'GetElementType' but this appears on both

Comment: pass the actual `$ie.Document` object

Answer (score 0):

the following works both on my Windows 10 workstation as well as on a Windows Server 2012

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") |  where-object {$_.innerText -eq "Go to app"}
```

Comment: Without the "IHTMLDocument3_" I have this error on both machines:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At D:\script.ps1:54 char:1
+ $Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.inner ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\script.ps1:55 char:1
+ $link.click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull